# python using multiprocessing pool.map for distributed computing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

The next code works to execute "someprogram" in parallel for the 50 inputfilenames, using a pool of 5 workers. How is it possible to use 5 workers on
this computer, and 7 on another computer, using only the standard libraries like multiprocessing. Ideally i would have a list tuples (hostname, amountofworkers), which can be used to speed up something, and maybe turn it into a decorator so that it can be reused more easily on methods like the "commandlinestuff". (Using linux and python 2.7)

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def commandlinestuff(inputfilename):
    p = subprocess.Popen("someprogram "+inputfilename, shell=True)
    p.wait()

inputfilenames = ["something"+str(i).zfill(2)+".in" for i in range(50)]
p = multiprocessing.pool(5)
p.map(commandlinestuff, inputfilenames)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/distributed-python-for-scripting/ did the trick for me - nothing to install, and seems to be the shortest/easiest way possible to do multiprocessing in python

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to re-invent [pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) which is itself written in pure python but is not currently a part of the standard libraries.

Basically you need a server running on the remote machine(s) that accepts a connection, receives a pickled object to execute, (and possibly some data), executes it and posts back a result.  You will also need a client on the local machine that does the posts, gathers the results and possibly does some load balancing.

The Parallel Processing entry in the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) gives a long list of tools to do this sort of thing with various advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: sadly, only standard libraries available -